# Why does the memory behave differently after applying strcpy() and initialising an array with a string literal?

Tags: arrays, c, memory

If I assign an array a string literal using `strcpy`, I can easily access those bytes which are beyond the array bounds:

```
char sequence[4];
strcpy(sequence, "String");
printf("&sequence == %p\n", &sequence);
printf("&sequence[3] == %p\n", &sequence[3]);
printf("The out-of-range values are '%c' and '%c'\n", *(char*)0x000000000022FE50, *(char*)0x000000000022FE51);

&sequence == 000000000022FE4C
&sequence[3] == 000000000022FE4F
The out-of-range values are 'n' and 'g'
```

But if I do the same thing merely initialising the array in place, these memory bytes are empty or have some unexpected values:

```
char sequence[4] = "String";    
printf("&sequence == %p\n", &sequence);
printf("&sequence[3] == %p\n", &sequence[3]);
printf("The out-of-range values are '%c' and '%c'\n", *(char*)0x000000000022FE50, *(char*)0x000000000022FE51);

&sequence == 000000000022FE4C
&sequence[3] == 000000000022FE4F
The out-of-range values are ' ' and 'r'
```

Why is there such difference between `strcpy` and direct storing?

**Disclaimer:**
**I know that this programme is incorrect.**  I know what undefined behavior is, I know that it is bad and should not be considered as a solution ever. The question is only about mechanisms and only seeks educational purposes. I am never about to apply this to any practical task (if anyone worries that much).

Comment: The initialization of `char sequence[4]` writes exactly 4 bytes. The function call `strcpy(sequence, "whatever")` writes as many bytes (invoking UB) as there are in `"whatever"`

Comment: @pmg doesn't `strcpy` accept an array as a pointer? Maybe that is the answer

Comment: As far as `strcpy()` is concerned, it only receives pointers. An array sent from the caller gets converted automatically to a pointer by the compilation process

Comment: What compiler are you using? Doesn't it complain about `char sequence[4] = "String";`?!?! It is a constraint violation!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala some compilers may raise a warning. Actually there is no bound checking like in Java, one should always watch their array bounds

Comment: A C compiler must raise a warning, otherwise it is not a C compiler. Both of your programs are **invalid programs**, but C standard allows a compiler to successfully compile an **invalid program**; it is just **required** to issue a message for the *latter* case. It would be totally OK to **refuse** to compile the latter fragment.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know that, please do not tell me that the programme is invalid (check the comment below the first answer)

Comment: no, the program has a constraint violation, a C compiler can initialize more than 4 characters in that case, or, anything goes.

Comment: "It works on different compilers" does not mean that the program is correct. It just means that some compilers let you get away with that.

Comment: Notice that your pointer values are wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala which ones?

Comment: Ah nvm, it is supposed to be outside the string, and it was, now that I checked again.

Comment: It isn't "just" undefined behavior, it isn't valid C. Regarding constraint violations and "the compiler only gave a warning" please see [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277340).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, I intentionally tried to mess around with bytes which were not supposed to be messed around with. Just curiosity, what is bad with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I assign an array a string literal using strcpy, I can easily access those bytes which are beyond the array bounds:

No, you cannot. This is undefined behavior. It may work. It may not. Don't do that. Whenever you "can" access out of bounds elements, you're doing something wrong.

You could avoid this with `strncpy(sequence, "String", sizeof(sequence))`

> Why is there such difference between strcpy and direct storing?

`strcpy` have no knowledge of the size of the array you're passing to it, but the compiler has that knowledge during compilation. An implementation of `strcpy` can look like this:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source ) {
    char *ret = destination;
    while(source) {
        *destination = *source;
        destination++;
        source++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you initialize an array, this is what the [C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

If the string literal is too long, the remaining characters will be ignored. Do note that this will most likely lead to a string without zero termination. So this is not a valid string and printing it will invoke Undefined behavior. However, this code is ok, even if it will issue a warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[8]="Hi!\0This initializer is too long";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str); i++)
        putchar(str[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

It will print:

```
Hi!
Hi!This
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221572/discussion-on-answer-by-klutt-why-does-the-memory-behave-differently-after-apply).